# ODE and global solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the problem $x'=-x^3,x(0)=x_0.$

I was wondering if it's possible to prove that this problem has a global solution (on $[0,U],$ for every $U>0$) without solving it: considering $\psi:C([0,U],\mathbb{R}) \to C([0,U],\mathbb{R}),\psi(x)(r)=x_0-\int_0^r(x(q))^3dq$ for $r\in [0,U],x \in C([0,U],\mathbb{R})$ (space of continuous functions equipped with the supremum norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\sup}$), define $\Vert x \Vert_\lambda=\sup_{r\in [0,U]}e^{-\lambda r}|x(r)|,C'=\{ y \in C([0,U],\mathbb{R}),\Vert y\Vert_{\sup} \leq R\},$ for convenient condition on $R$ and $U$ so that $C'$ is complete (for $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\lambda}$) and invariant by $\psi,$ we can also choose $\lambda$ so that $\psi$ is a contraction on $C'$ and we can apply a fixed point argument to prove that a local solution exists (which make sense since $u\to -u^3$ is locally Lipchitz).

How to obtain a global solution? Is it possible to apply a fixed point argument to obtain it?

Comment: You can solve this equation explicitly separating the variables. It is not true that you have global solutions on any $[0,U]$. Your solutions blow up after some time depending on the initial value.

Comment: @Meowdog : This would be the case for the equation $x'=-x^2$. But with the cube on the right side the solution set is mirror symmetric over the horizontal axis. Or in other words, if $x$ is a solution, $-x$ is likewise a solution.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right of course.

Comment: This problem is easily solved using the stability theory. Consider the Lyapunov function $V=\frac12 x^2$. It is radially unbounded, $\dot V=2x(-x^3)=-2x^4$ is negative-definite, thus, the system is globally asymptotically stable, which implies existence of a solution for any initial conditions.